# Pandas chaining only modifying one column in dataframe using apply or pipe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean a file using pandas chaining and I have come to a point where I only need to clean one column and leave the rest as is, is there a way to accomplished this using pandas chaining using apply or pipe.

I have tried the following which works, but I only would like to replace the dash in one specific column and leave the the rest as is since the dash in other columns is appropriate.

```
df = (dataFrame
    .dropna()
    .pipe(lambda x: x.replace("-", "", regex=True))

)
```

I have also tried this, which doesn't work since it only returns the seatnumber column.

```
df = (dataFrame
    .dropna()
    .pipe(lambda x: x['seatnumber'].replace("-", "", regex=True))

)
```

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a column with the same name of the column of interest:

```
df = (dataFrame
      .dropna()
      .assign(seatnumber=lambda x: x.seatnumber.replace("-", "", regex=True))
)
```

where the dataframe at that point is passed to the `lambda` as `x`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let us pass a `dict`

```
df = (dataFrame
    .dropna().replace({"seatnumber" : {"-":""}}, regex=True)

)
```